# How can I change the color of inside borders only for header columns?

Tags: templates, sas, rtf, ods

I want to have output a table into RTF that has no lines inside the table but has the inside border in header cells. In addition, the header column is colorful. I know how to change the border color for all the cells but I can't figure out how to only change the header ones. I need to do it with proc template. Right now I get this table:

[image]

But I need to have it like this:

[image]

The code is :

```
proc template;
define style styles.new;
parent = Styles.Printer;

replace color_list /
'link' = blue 
'bgH' = cxFF8200 
'bgT' = white 
'bgD' = white 
'fg' = black
'bg' = white; 

replace Table from Output /
frame = hsides 
rules = groups 
cellpadding = 2pt 
cellspacing = 0.25pt 
borderwidth = 0.75pt 
background = color_list('bgt') ;

end;
run;
ods listing style=new;
```

Could someone tell me please how could I change the code to get the correct output?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The white column header separation 'lines' you are seeing are not actually drawn.

Change to `cellspacing=1in` and you will observe that the 'lines' are actually artifacts of the spacing and correspond to the overall background.  I don't think there is an easy way to have header cell borders that are different than data cell borders.